# OnsenUIの基本的な構成方法

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui

全くのMonaca初心者です。初歩的な質問で申し訳ありません。
controller等を設けず、OnsenUIを利用して
onclick等で普段通りのJSで関数を書いて行ってしまいました。
Pushpageでページを切り替えていくことができましたが、切り替えたページでは
DOMを書き換えることもできませんでした。
Psuhpage後にロードされたDOMに対して、データを表示させたりするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか

Comment: 1件目の回答に、page.target.id の指定方法と、ページに関する処理についてコメントしてみましたが、解決しましたか？

Answer (score 1):

私も初心者ですので、初心者の視点から・・・。
コードがないのではっきりしたことは言えませんが、JavaScriptが実行されるタイミングが問題かもしれません。ページ切り替えボタンをタッチした瞬間など、各要素が構築される「前」にDOMに対する制御をかけてしまうと、望んだ結果が得られません。
試行錯誤でしたが、私は以下のイベントリスナーをセットすることで対処しました。

```
document.addEventListener('pageinit',function(page){
if(page.target.id=="Page1"){
    initPage1(); //ページ１の初期化処理
　 } 
if(page.target.id=="Page2"){
    initPage2();//ページ２の初期化処理
　 }
 }
```

※`page.target.id=="Page1"` で比較されているページ名は、 `<ons-page id="Page1">` で指定したIdが入ります。

”pageinit”は、各要素が構築されたのちに実行されるイベントですので、Pushされたページに対しても、各要素にアクセスできると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
page.target.id はどこで指定しますでしょうか？
Index.htmlには`<ons-button onclick="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html')">Next Page</ons-button>` とかいてあります。 またpage2.html内に書かれていることは `<ons-button onclick="Camera()">Next Page</ons-button>` onclickで、カメラapiのサンプル通りのメソッドは呼び出す事ができます。 完了後にべつのページに飛んだ先の要素を書き換えたいです。
JQuery のclickなどは利用できますでしょうか

Comment: 文字が消えてしまっていましたね。
※page.target.id=="Page1"　で比較されているページ名は、<ons-page id="Page1">という風に、ons-Pageタグで指定したIdが入ります。

Comment: ページに関する処理についてですが、ons-navigator を使用したシングルページアプリケーションでは、通常のHTMLのページに関する考え方と異なっている気がします。私の感覚では、一つのページに、PushPageで呼び出された次のページを重ねていったり、PopPageで取り除いていくイメージです。ですから、何枚かのページが重なっている状態（ページスタック）になり、すでに読み込んでいるページ（重なっているページ）の要素に対しては、JQueryからアクセス可能です。

Comment: 話がずれるかもしれませんが、私も最初これだけでずっとやっていたのですが限界が来たので、angularを習得してコントローラー側で処理するようにしました。